# I dont get "Import Project from Maven" dialog

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, ctakes

I am new to Java

and following the instructions of how to install an open source application.

Steps are here

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CTAKES/cTAKES+4.0+Developer+Install+Guide#cTAKES4.0DeveloperInstallGuide-IntelliJIDEAstepbystepinstallinstructions

In **Import Project from Maven** section, step number **4**

```
4. Click "Ok".
This will open an "Import Project from Maven" dialog.
```

I click ok but no other dialog opens

Here is what I get

[image]

[image]

I have googled and I found another website that says I should get Improt Project from Maven

someting like this

[image]
[image]

**How can I get this screen so I follow instructions of the installation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should get Improt Project as Maven Project from import Project at IntelliJ idea
first import project which contains pom.xml file then select import as maven
[image: import Project]

[image: select folder which contains pom.xml]

[image: then select maven]

Comment: Thanks,I got the dialog, but do u know how 2 get the rest of the points? 5. Make sure the "Search for projects recursively" box is selected, just in case any cTakes modules are not in the pom. 6. Make sure that "Create IntelliJ IDEa modules for aggregator projects" is not selected. If you plan to add new module, 'disable' a present cTakes module or make other changes to the main pom.xml, check the "Import Maven projects automatically" box. 
7. Make sure that "Create module rgoups for multi-module Maven projects" is not selected.

Answer (score 1):

1. Start IntelliJ IDEA (2019.3).
2. In the wizard, click "Import Project".
3. In the dialog that opens, select pom.xml of your project and click "OK".
   IntelliJ IDEA opens and syncs the project in the IDE.

If you need to adjust the Maven settings:
1. Go to Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Buildtools | Maven | Importing. On this page, adjust the settings according to your preferences, click "OK" to save the changes. 
2. Reimport your project. (click the "Reimport all Maven Projects" icon in the Maven tool window)[image] 
Additional links to the docs:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_import_project_start